# How to get all the countries name in french and english with CultureInfo?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want in my dropdownlist all the countries name in french or in english. It will depend on a condition.

**Here's my function:**

```
private void PopulateDropDownList()
{
    List<string> cultureList = new List<string>();
    CultureInfo[] getCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

    // I fill my list cultureList with countries
    foreach (CultureInfo getCulture in getCultureInfo)
    {
        RegionInfo getRegionInfo = new RegionInfo(getCulture.LCID);
        if (!(cultureList.Contains(getRegionInfo.EnglishName)))
        {
            cultureList.Add(getRegionInfo.EnglishName);
        }
    }
    // Sort the list to get all the countries in order
    cultureList.Sort();

    // Fill my DropDownList ddlCountry with my list of countries
    ddlCountry.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select a country", ""));
    foreach (string country in cultureList)
    {
        ddlCountry.Items.Add(new ListItem(country, country));
    }
}
```

**My asp page:**

```
<label class="control-label">Country</label>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCountry" CssClass="form-control c-square c-theme">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

For now, all the countries are in english. My question is simple: **How do I set the language in French directly in my function PopulateDropDownList()?**

Comment: Pls feel free to correct my poor english ^^

Comment: The `RegionInfo` object has a `NativeName` property that gives the name in the region's native language.  I don't see anything that will give you the name in French, unless you have the French language version of .NET installed.  There's a property called `DisplayName` property that, "Gets the full name of the country/region in the language of the localized version of .NET Framework."

Comment: I actually need both languages, not only french.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you install the necessary language packs to your system, you can get it as

```
var orgCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"); //<-- *****
var countries = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                .Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID))
                .Select(x => x.DisplayName)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(x=>x)
                .ToList();
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = orgCulture;
```